# How to solve the aiogram library error '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'?

Tags: python, bots, aiogram

I am learning python and mastering aiogram library for writing bots.
Now I'm learning and in the lesson about Middleware, problems arose.
Writing a bot, the bot should filter frequent pressing `/start` (almost like the official example on the site aiogram)
Code for the lesson is done, the basics are understood. But in the final output comes an error

```
\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 1303, in throttle
result = delta >= rate or delta <= 0
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

I understand that the data in result is not correct, but I can't figure it out myself =((((
Help please.

Aiogram 2.19

There is a suggestion that the data does not go correctly in the middlewares/throttling.py from the decorator in handlers/start.py and misc/throttling.py

Here is the code of those files:
middlewares/throttling.py

```
import asyncio
import logging
from typing import Union

from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher import DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import current_handler, CancelHandler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware

from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled


class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):

    def __init__(self, limit=DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT, key_prefix="antiflood_"):
        self.limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def throttle(self, target: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery]):
        handler = current_handler.get()
        if not handler:
            return
        dp = Dispatcher.get_current()
        limit = getattr(handler, "throttling_rate_limit", self.limit)
        key = getattr(handler, "throttling_key", f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")

        try:
            await dp.throttle(key, rate=limit)
        except Throttled as t:
            await self.target_throttled(target, t, dp, key)
            raise CancelHandler()

    @staticmethod
    async def target_throttled(target: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery],
                               throttled: Throttled, dispatcher: Dispatcher, key: str):
        msg = target.message if isinstance(target, types.CallbackQuery) else target
        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta
        if throttled.exceeded_count == 2:
            await msg.reply("Слишком часто! Давай не так быстро.")
            return
        elif throttled.exceeded_count == 3:
            await msg.reply(f"Всё! Больше не отвечу! - пока не пройдет {delta} секунд.")
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(delta)

        thr = await dispatcher.check_key(key)
        logging.info(f"{thr.exceeded_count=}. {throttled.exceeded_count=}")
        if thr.exceeded_count == throttled.exceeded_count:
            await msg.reply("Все, теперь отвечаю.")

    async def on_process_message(self, message, data):
        await self.throttle(message)

    async def on_process_callback_query(self, call, data):
        await self.throttle(call)
```

handlers/start.py

```
import logging

from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import CommandStart

from tgbot.filters.test_filter import SomeF
from tgbot.misc.throttling import rate_limit


@rate_limit(5, key="start")
async def bot_start(message: types.Message, middleware_data, from_filter):
    await message.answer(f"Привет, {message.from_user.full_name}! \n{middleware_data=} \n{from_filter=}")
    logging.info(f"6. Handler")
    logging.info("Следующая точка: Post Process Message")
    return {"from_handler": "Данные из хендлера"}


def register_bot_start(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(bot_start, CommandStart(), SomeF())
```

misc/throttling.py

```
def rate_limit(limit: int, key=None):
    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, "throttling_rate_limit", limit)
        if key:
            setattr(func, "throttling_rate_limit", key)
        return func

    return decorator
```

Very much looking for help, the training is up =(

Answer (score 1):

The error was here

```
def rate_limit(limit: int, key=None):
    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, "throttling_rate_limit", limit)
        if key:
            setattr(func, "throttling_rate_limit", key)
        return func

    return decorator
```

That's right
if key:
setattr(func, "**throttling_key**", key)

Answer (score 0):

```
#let's do this

from aiogram.dispatcher import DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT # you need this, and LIMIT time must be INT not FLOAT (I think)
# if DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT have not in aiogram.dispatcher create it yourself --> DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT = {any int number #sec}

@staticmethod
async def target_throttled(target: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery],
                               throttled: Throttled, dispatcher: Dispatcher, key: str):
        msg = target.message if isinstance(target, types.CallbackQuery) else target
        delta = DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT # not this --> throttled.rate - throttled.delta
        if throttled.exceeded_count == 2:
            await msg.reply(f"Слишком часто! Давай не так быстро.{throttled.result}")
            return
        elif throttled.exceeded_count == 3:
            await msg.reply(f"Всё! Больше не отвечу! - пока не пройдет {delta} секунд.")
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(delta)

        thr = await dispatcher.check_key(key)
        logging.info(f"{thr.exceeded_count=}. {throttled.exceeded_count=}")
        if thr.exceeded_count == throttled.exceeded_count:
            await msg.reply("Все, теперь отвечаю.")
```